# Проблема с сервлетом Java

Tags: java, сервлеты

Суть сервлета такова - есть форма на ней два поля для ввода, в них я ввожу числа, после должен сработать сервлет, который вернет сумму этих двух чисел. 
Код файла для формы ниже ( при нажатии на кпопку должен сработать метод Get, сервлета CalculateServlet )

```
<form action="CalculateServlet" method="GET">               
    <p align="center"><font size="5"><b>CalculationForm</b></font></p>
                    <TABLE ALIGN="center" height="57">
                    <TR>
                          <TD >
                          <b>Enter First Number:</b>
                          </TD>
                          <TD >
                          <input type="text" name="number1" size="20" >
                          </TD>
                    </TR>

                    <TR>
                          <TD >
                          <b>Enter Second Number:</b>
                          </TD>
                          <TD >
                          <input type="text" name="number2" size="20" >
                          </TD>
                    </TR>
                    <TR align="center">
                          <TD colspan=5>
                          <input type="Submit" value="Add">
                          </TD>
                    </TR>
                    </TABLE>
                    </form>
```

Вот листинг самого сервлета

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/CalculateServlet")
public class CalculateServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        /* Получение чисел, введенных пользователем в HTML-форме */
        int num1 = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("number1"));
        int num2 = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("number2"));
        /* Нахождение суммы чисел, введенных пользователем. */
        int result = num1 + num2;

        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
        /* вывод результата */
        pw.println("<h3>The result of the calculation is: " +Integer.toString(result)+"<h3>");
        pw.close();
    }
```

При запуске приложения вылетает ошибка 404 - /Calculate_2(имя проекта)/CalculateServlet(имя сервлета)     The requested resource is not available. Я так понимаю сервлет каким-то образом не может быть найден обработчиком кнопки что на html - форме ?

Comment: Ваш сервлет отвечает по адресу CalculateServlet,  не думаю что вы должны указывать имя проекта. Так как используется Get метод то вы можете его тестировать прямо в  строке адреса броузера

Comment: какой адрес вы используете чтобы загрузить страницу? Адрес страницы должен быть что то вроде localhost:8080/Calculate_2/index.jsp, тогда при нажатии на кнопку браузер засабмитит форму по адресу _http://localhost:8080/Calculator_2/CalcualteServlet?number1=2&number2=2_ . Вы можете посмотреть запрос посылаемый при нажатии на кнопку используя dev tools в браузере. Ваш код верен, я просто думаю что вы открываете страницу не из того места

Comment: Какой используется сервер приложений? Какая среда разработки? В большинстве случаев адрес в браузере должен быть `http://localhost:8080/Calculate_2/CalculateServlet`. Не устанавливали Context root в значение, отличное от значения по умолчанию? Тогда адрес будет `http://localhost:8080/Ваш_context_root/CalculateServlet` Кроме того, как показала практика, некоторые используют встраиваемые сервера, где contextpath формируется иначе. Адрес может оказаться и таким `http://localhost:8080/CalculateServlet`. (Вместо порта 8080 подставьте свой)